# How do you move to a right tab in a column of a table within a Google document?

Tags: google-docs

I wish to type a price list in a table on a Google document. I highlight the column, set a right tab on the ruler to align the amounts of money in the column, but cannot find how to move the figures across the cell to align from the right (in the middle of the cell - not on right margin).

Answer (score 1):

I think Google needs to do quite a lot more work on Tables and the alignment you seek seems extremely unintuitive (perhaps not helped where the response is not instant). However, it does seem to be possible. First I would clear the formatting from the column (so don't put a tab stop in the middle). I think by default you should see the little blue arrow, as ringed in red:

[image: WA94612 first example]

Right align the column (from the menu bar), then drag that little blue arrow as far to the left as required:

[image: WA94612 second example]